# How to check if Django 1.3 project is also compatible with Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, compatibility

I working on project where I must use things from an existing Django application. The application is written with Django 1.3. Is there a way to determine if it is possible to use it for a project that use in Django 1.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to build a virtualenv with Django 1.6, install your app, and run its tests. There will likely be some small breaks—Django has changed since 1.3—but they should be relatively easy to patch up.

Comment: Is there some script (like 2to3) that could help to patch up. I doubt that exist but I want to be sure.

Comment: There isn't a tool, but the release notes for the intervening versions (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/, and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/) walk you through the API changes, which should provide a good guide on what you'll need to alter.